# Enzyme simulate with 1 node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following test case in react-native.

```
  it('changes text', () => {
    wrapper.find(InputBox).simulate('change', { target: { value: 'text Given' } });
  });
```

There are 2 InputBoxes so this gives me an error saying 'simulate should run on a single node, but found 2'.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of selectors such as `first` or `at`. For instance, say you want to select the first `InputBox`, you will write:

```
 wrapper.find(InputBox).first().simulate('change', { target: { value: 'text Given' } });
```

In the same way you can use `last` to get the last of matched nodes or `at(index)` to select matches by index.